# Superset oracle configuration

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, apache-superset

I'm trying to configure Superset, but when I try to configure a new database to connect to oracle, I have problems,

Superset uses sqlalchemy for db connection, I define tnsname to connect and pass to superset as say documentation http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/engines.html#database-urls
oracle+cx_oracle://ifn:XXXXXX@DBDESA but produces an error

(TypeError: expecting None or a string)

separatly i try to do a connection with sqlalchemy for test the connection

```
    Import sqlalchemy as sa
    Eng = sa.create_engine ('oracle + cx_oracle: // ifn: XXXXXX @ DBDESA')
    Eng.execute ('select 1 from dual') fetchall ()
```

But i get the same error, is there another needed configuration? Encoding or someting for connect to oracle XE? Or aditional params in superset configuration?

Tnsnames.ora

```
    DBDESA =
            (Description =
                    (Address_list =
            (Address = (protocol = TCP) (host = XXX.XX.X.X) (port = 1524)))
            (Connect_data = (Service_name = dbdesa)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **URI** syntax may be wrong.

Please try to set the **URI** by referring to the example below:

```
oracle+cx_oracle://dbname:password@ipaddress:port/?service_name=yourtnsname
```

For example:

```
oracle+cx_oracle://test_db:test_password@10.22.3.202:1521/?service_name=hoge
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the documentation says that oracle is supported, you will have a hard time making it work.

For instance:

1. Superset assumes that the autoincrement is supported by the DB, which is not the case for oracle. You will need to create all the sequences in Oracle and add references to them in your domain classes. You have to do that in superset code `superset/models/core.py`, as well as in the migrations `superset/migrations/*` (look for every place where a table is created).
2. Oracle does not support identifiers (foreign key or column names) with more than 30 characters. You will need to do some renamings.
3. on `superset/migrations/env.py`, after:

```
if engine.name in ('sqlite', 'mysql'):
    kwargs = {
        'transaction_per_migration': True,
        'transactional_ddl': True,
 }
```

add a similar block for oracle as below:

```
if engine.name in ('oracle'):
        kwargs = {
            'transactional_ddl': True,
  }
```

Notice that I removed the `transaction_per_migration` parameter. And you can also use equals instead of *"in"* :)

4. on the dialect `site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/oracle/base.px`
   add "rows" as a reserved word `./base.py:360:RESERVED_WORDS`
5. Do that again every time you want to upgrade superset.
6. **Give up this mess and use Mysql**

Comment: Thanks for the  tips. The behaviour I'm seeing with vanilla superset is that for oracle 12c it works in SQL editor. It also works for visualising if I select just one row. Trying to select more than one row doesn't show anything. Does that line up with your experience?